# How to set the background in a JPanel without using the super call in paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, setbackground

In this program, I want to draw a series of lines that interact to form a web. Each time the timer ticks, a line is drawn. Therefore, I cannot have the `super.paintComponent(g)` call in the `paintComponent()` because I need the previous lines to appear. However, I would like to set the background colour and as far as I've found, the `setBackground()` method can be called only if the super call is first made. I am not sure if the `fillRect` method would work either because it would draw a rectangle over the old line each time. I tried having the `setBackground()` method in the constructor, and it did not work either.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class prettyWebPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  Timer time = new Timer(100,this);
  private Color colour1 = Color.black;
  private Color colour2 = Color.white;
  JButton start = new JButton("Start");
  int j = 0;

  public prettyWebPanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension (550,550));
    this.add(start);
    start.addActionListener(this);
    setBackground(colour1);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    setBackground(colour1);
    setForeground(colour2);
    if (j<490) g.drawLine(20, 20+j, 20+j, 500);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == start) time.start();
    else if (e.getSource() == time) {
      j+=10;
      repaint();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Therefore, I cannot have the super.paintComponent(g) call in the paintComponent() because I need the previous lines to appear."*  Your entire approach to painting is wrong.  Drop it and use the conventional approaches.  One way to avoid re-drawing previous work is to draw everything to a `BufferedImage` (then you might as well display that image in a `JLabel`).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/155831) where the best approach is entirely different to the question asked.

Comment: Use fillRect() to paint your background as you like in paintComponent method is fine.

Comment: @xiaowang if I call fillRect() each time, it will paint the rectangle over the previously drawn lines right?

Comment: Oh I was being silly. I realized I could use an if statement to just paint the rectangle once! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> because I need the previous lines to appear.

Then you need to do incremental painting. See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two common ways to do this:

1. Keep a `List` of objects to paint and repaint them every time
2. Do the painting onto a `BufferedImage`.